# How can pass data/variable from file_controller.rb to application.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have

```
@send_variable = 'show value in alert'
```

in controller file. In application.js, I want to do something like :

```
var receive_variable =  <%@send_variable %>; 
alert(receive_variable ); >>> screen show 'show value  in alert'
```

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `@send_variable` won't be available in `application.js` because it's a javascript file.  You do however have the option of alerting the value placed in a hidden div once your action template is rendered.

Something like follows:

```
# Controller
def action
  @send_variable = 'show value in alert' 
end

# app/view/action.html.erb
# Note in your 'hidden' css class you need to set it to 'visibility: hidden;'
<%= "<div id='send_variable' class='hidden'>#{@send_variable}</div>" if @send_variable %>

# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('load', '#send_variable', function(evt) {
    alert($('#send_variable').text());
  });
});
```

Another approach is to use [`remote: true`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) in either your link or button that calls this action.  Doing so will make a ajax call to the action and you can use the `js` format to execute your js action view template.

Something like following:

```
# Controller
def action
  @send_variable = 'show value in alert' 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end

# app/view/action.js.erb
alert("<%= j @send_variable %>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add = to print

```
var receive_variable =  '<%= @send_variable %>';
alert(receive_variable );
```

or just

```
alert('<%= @send_variable %>');
```

Also, check http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html for JS conventions

Comment: I did it and it alert '<%= @send_variable %>' instead of 'show value in alert'. :(

Comment: that means you only have only .html you need .erb.html to be able to use <% %> to embed ruby code.

Comment: S.ALQuaheeb how can I include application.js.erb to my project like application.js bro?

Comment: You can, but first read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html and search application.js.erb

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript, you have to enclose the instance-variable (@send_variable) with quotes.

```
alert('<%=@send_variable%>');
```

Assuming that @send_variable is a something like integer, the quotes ain't necessary.

This should do.

Comment: when I do alert('<%=@send_variable%>'); in view it shows 'show value  in alert' 
when I do alert('<%=@send_variable%>'); in application.js, it shows '<%=@send_variable%>'. how can I use '<%=@send_variable%>' in application.js file.

Comment: I guess, your end-goal is to alert the value of @send_variable (i.e 'show value in alert')? Correct? So, using alert('<%=@send_variable%>') will do.

Comment: You rather use the code that I suggested in the corresponding view-file of the request, not the in the application.js. This should do the trick.

Comment: [Midori](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3020985/midori) you can't use ruby code in application.js file. Because ruby code can be executed from ruby file like .rb or .erb extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the 'gon' gem (https://github.com/gazay/gon), which allows you to set javascript variables from anywhere in your rails code, using something like gon.variable_name = value, and subsequently use it in any javascript, like gon.variable_name. I used to use the above mentioned techniques, but 'gon' makes it all much easier, as it literally acts as a window between rails and javascript